# Can pattern matching be used in MySQL for consecutive rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, pattern-matching, mariadb-10.1

I have a very simple table, similar to:

```
id  | val
----------
1   | 20
2   | 22
3   | 29
4   | 21
5   | 14
6   | 9
7   | 15
```

I want to be able to identify a pattern in consecutive rows. For example, if the input is "29, 21, 14", there are three consecutive rows that match and I want to return:

```
id  | val
----------
3   | 29
4   | 21
5   | 14
```

If the rows are not consecutive there is no match.

My attempt, which does not work:

```
SELECT id as firstid, val from tbl100 WHERE `val` = '29' AND firstid+1 = '21' AND firstid+2 = '14'
```

The problem is obviously that my query finds val 29, then looks for id 21 and id 14, it should look for val 21 and val 14, but I have no idea how to do that.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: so you are specifically looking for the pattern of val 29, 21, 14, and no other?  what makes rows consecutive, ids being in order with no interposing rows, or something else?

Comment: Consecutive as in no interposing rows. I am using HeidiSQL 9.5, select version() shows 10.1.37-MariaDB

Comment: I am not specifically looking for that pattern, it will be whatever the user inputs, but for the purpose of figuring out the query syntax we can use that pattern. I will drop the user input into vars and use the vars in the query.

Comment: the easiest way to do this is with the lag() or lead() function, but that requires mariadb 10.2 or mysql 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first find the matching rows and then check for sequential `id`s with `lead` and `lag`:

```
with m_vals as (
   select t1.* from t t1 join i t2 on t1.val = t2.val
)
select t3.id, t3.val from (select m.*, lag(m.id) over (order by m.id) l, lead(m.id) over (order by m.id) t from m_vals m) t3
where (t3.l is null or t3.l + 1 = t3.id) and (t3.t is null or t3.t - 1 = t3.id)
```

Comment: Ajax1234, you are way over my head, but many thanks. I will look into lag and lead.

Comment: @blogo Glad to help. You might find [this](https://riptutorial.com/sql/example/27455/lag-and-lead) link on `lead` and `lag` helpful.